# select unique rows with distinct column

Tags: sql, select

Задача состоит в том, чтобы выбрать уникальные записи из таблицы:

```
Bezeichnung  Norm       d   P    dw
M14 x 130   ISO 4014    14  2    19,15
M14 x 140   ISO 4014    14  2    19,15
M18 x 70    ISO 4014    18  2,5  24,85
M18 x 80    ISO 4014    18  2,5  24,85
M22 x 220   ISO 4014    22  2,5  31,35
M22 x 90    ISO 4014    22  2,5  31,35
M36 x 340   ISO 4014    36  4    51,11
M36 x 140   ISO 4014    36  4    51,11
M20 x 100   ISO 4014    20  2,5  27,7
M20 x 110   ISO 4014    20  2,5  27,7
```

желаемый результат следующий (уникальные записи по d):

```
Bezeichnung  Norm       d   P    dw
M14 x 130   ISO 4014    14  2    19,15
M18 x 70    ISO 4014    18  2,5  24,85
M22 x 220   ISO 4014    22  2,5  31,35
M36 x 340   ISO 4014    36  4    51,11
M20 x 100   ISO 4014    20  2,5  27,7
```

Каким должен быть sql запрос?

Comment: Хорошо, допустим мы возьмём уникальные записи по `d`. А по какому принципу оставим другие колонки?

Comment: Заодно - Вас устроит, если в остальные поля попадут значения из **разных** записей с одинаковым id?

Comment: уникальным в свою очередь должны быть: d, P, dw.

Comment: Поле "Bezeichnung" выбирается любое из двух (оптимальное решение). Поле "Norm"  одинаковое для всех.

Comment: делаете `group by d, p, dw` от всех остальных полей берете min или max, по своему усмотрению

Comment: _уникальным в свою очередь должны быть: d, P, dw_ - одновременно? или нужны три разных запроса, в каждом что-то одно уникально?

Comment: Поля d, P, dw должны быть уникальными одновременно (если можно написать запрос используя уникальность по одному полю тоже приемлемо).